# How to click on all buttons in a single webpage using automation tool

Tags: automation, shopify

I am importing products using oberlo. But the thing is I need all the products from oberlo and it is really hard to select one by one to import list as there are too  many pages. So I am searching for some kind of script or tool which will automatically click the import button for each and every product.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You could use a webdriver-based solution (e.g. selenium-webdriver).

Comment: Well webdriver will create new instance every time i call. I have acheived using javascript.